# DDD: return pagination informations from my repository to API response in NodeJS

Tags: api, repository, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have a API than return a user list /api/user :

```
[{
  id: 1,
  firstname: 'toto',
  lastname: 'titi'
},
{
  ...
}]
```

Now I want add a pagination informations from my UserRepository

```
{
  result: [{
    id: 1,
    firstname: 'toto',
    lastname: 'titi'
  },
  {
    ...
  }],
  pagination: {
    totalPages: 75,
    page: 2,
    limit: 25
  }
}
```

My controller (interface layer)

```
...
router.get('/users', ctx => {
    getUsersUseCase
      .execute(ctx.state.limit, ctx.state.offset)
      .then(data => {
        ctx.response.status = Status.OK;
        ctx.response.body = data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ctx.response.status = Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        ctx.response.body = error;
      });
  });

...
```

In my application layer, I have a `getUsers` use case :

```
// app/getUsers.js
module.exports = () => {
  const execute = (limit, offset) => {
    const userListPaginated = userRepository.find(limit, offset);

    return userListPaginated; // before it returned just a User Array
  };

  return {
    execute,
  };
};
```

My domain User model:

```
// domain/User.js
module.exports = {
  id: Integer,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
}
```

My domain UserListPaginated model:

```
// domain/UserListPaginated.js
module.exports = {
  result: [], // User list
  pagination: {}, // pagination informations
}
```

And in my UserRepository (I using https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2 for the pagination information):

```
    class UserRepository {
      constructor({ model }) {
        this.userModel = model; // mongoose model
      }

      async find(limit, offset) {
        var userListPaginated;

        this.userModel.paginate({}, { offset, limit }).then(function(result) {
         userListPaginated = { 
           result: result.docs,
           pagination: {
             totalPages: result.totalPages
             limit: result.limit - 10
             offset: result.offset
           }
        });

        return userListPaginated; // before returned just a array of user model

      }
```

My problem, I think, is that the pagination informations not concern the Domain (in the UserListPaginated.js).
It is just here to be return to the API controller. But I need to return this information from the repository and cross the domain layer.

What is the good DDD pratrice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be a good idea to by-pass the domain model entirely for queries (CQRS). Let the domain model focus on writes/commands and deal with reads/queries elsewhere. For instance, you could have an `IUserQueryService` interface in the `application` layer which gets implemented in the `infrastructure` layer (it could even be implemented by the same repository class).

It's important to be pragmatic though. If you feel comfortable using domain entities directly in query results then polluting the repository's interface with query concerns such as pagination state could be acceptable. It's always a question of trade-offs and you shouldn't strive for pureness when it's not practical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the moment I not use CQRS in my Clean Architecture.

In my UserController if I call two use case (getUsers and getUserCount), do you think it is a better idea ? getUserCountUseCase is it a really good use case ?

Comment: @Mamin CQRS doesn't mean even sourcing and having an entirely different real model. It can be as simple as having 2 distinct services, one for queries and one for commands. Surely nothing prevents you from creating a new service in any architecture? Also note that command-related queries such as loading an aggregate is part of the command service model, not queries.

Comment: I do the same thing in the PHP. Write is supported by the Domain, but reads are handled by dedicated ReadModels. It does the job fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. For the moment I not use CQRS in my Clean Architecture.

In my UserController if I call two use case, do you think it is a better idea ? `getUserCountUseCase` is it a really good use case ?

```
router.get('/users', ctx => {
    const usersPromise = getUsersUseCase // Old use case (just a users array)
      .execute(ctx.state.limit, ctx.state.offset)

    const userCountPromise = getUserCountUseCase
      .execute(ctx.state.limit, ctx.state.offset)

    Promise.all([userCountPromise, usersPromise])
    .then((values) => {

      const [count, users] = values;

      const userListPaginated = {
         result:  users,
         pagination: {
           totalPages: count,
           page: Math.ceil((offset + 1) / limit),
           limit: ctx.state.limit
         }
      }

      ctx.response.status = Status.OK;
      ctx.response.body = userListPaginated;
    })

  });
```

Comment: According to my answer you'd consider getting a list of users a "query" use case where getting a single User AR for invoking a command on it would be part of the command logical model. The "query" use case API can deal with pagination state where the "command" use cases wouldn't. In other words, `usersListingUserCase.execute(limit, offset)` returns paginated result (perhaps even with `UserListingDto` instances where `userOfId.execute(userId)` would return a `User` AR. Under the hood both implementations can use the same query engine and strategy if needed, but they expose a different API.